# MSXML2: How can I get value of a node?

Tags: c++, msxml

I have this node

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr node;
```

`node->Getxml()` returns  `"<level3>333<level4 atribute="444"><level5>555<level6>666</level6></level5></level4></level3>"`

`node->Gettext();` returns `"333555666"`

`node->GetnodeValue()` throws exception if node is not an attribute.

How can I get the value `333` ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to walk the children of the node you have in hand - you can get a list using [childNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757053%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) after [checking the node has children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762646%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of course, then you can use `Gettext()` to extract the individual element texts.

It's quite painful to code to the MSXML DOM, in my experience.  Glad to see you are using the built-in smart pointers, anyway.

Comment: <level3> node has 2 childs. For first one Gettext returns whet I want (333) for the second returns 333555666. My code works fine if i use GetfirstChild and Gettext but will this method work without problems in any case ?

Comment: Why GetnodeValue doesn't work and throws exception if node is not an attribute node ?

Comment: The XML DOM is not quite intuitive.  In your example level3 is the parent node and 333 and level4 are its child nodes.  333 is a text node and level4 is an element node.